# Refresh external changes on mounted samba share

Tags: mount, samba, nas

I have a samba share running on a NAS and two laptops running ubuntu 23.04 accessing it as mounted drive (using cifs). So let's say I create a file on the mounted folder on laptop 1. Is there a way to have the mounted folder on laptop 2 refresh automatically to see the newly created file instead of having to hit F5 to refresh?